# Uncountable word "pain"

Tags: uncountable-nouns

As regards the word **pain** being uncountable, which of the following is correct:

> I had **a** severe pain last night.
>
> I had severe pain last night.

Comment: Either is correct. Pain can be both countable and uncountable. Cf. "aches and pains," etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The word pain can be both countable and uncountable. In the countable form, it tends to refer to a specific pain in a particular place and time. The uncountable form is used for the general concept.

> Pain can be controlled with some types of drug.
>
> I got a pain in my knee when I was running.

The countable form can also be used figuratively to mean an annoying person.

> My son is such a pain when he argues about homework.

In your case, you could use pain either countably or uncountably, but if you are referring to a specific pain then the countable form is more likely.